# Request on unstructured table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a question concerning how I can structurate my database for this kind of use case :

I have users & each user has several metadata I can't predict (and then can't put into columns).

For example:

User1 has country = Fr and site = Paris
User2 has country = GB and site = London, but also is_manager = true

In fact, the metadata count can vary, then I was thinking about using a schema like this one:

[image]

But I have no idea how to extract users with metadata country = Fr & site = Paris.
The only way I know is painfull by doing a request, and then using Python to finish what I can't do in SQL :

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_has_metadata UHM
JOIN user U
    ON UHM.user_id = U.id
JOIN metadata M
    ON UHM.metadata_id = M.id
WHERE UHM.value = "Fr" OR UHM.value = "Paris"
```

But this is not enough, I have to process the data after that. Is there a better way ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by " I have to process the data after that."? What is your "process"? I am only guessing you want to `GROUP BY U.id`

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text! (No images, please.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema you planned can fulfill your needs. The SELECT could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM user U
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_has_metadata UHM
    WHERE
        U.id=UHM.user_id
        AND UHM.value = "Fr"
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_has_metadata UHM2
    WHERE
        U.id=UHM2.user_id
        AND UHM2.value = "Paris"
)
```

BTW, I suggest to rename "id" to "user_id" in table USER, the name should reflect what the field contains, and should be called the same in all tables. Same for metadata_id.
Also, it would be better to compare the metadata_id values, and not the "value"s, because it may be the same for different metadata types.